# Returns Correct Class Name when Method Is Redefined in Extended Class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, object, syntax

I expected the first example code produces the result same as the second one but it didn't. So in order to get the correct class name, I have to redefine the custom `msg()` method in the extended class.

I'd like to know why the first one does not produce the extended class name and why it does when the method is redefined which is exactly the same.

**Example 1**

```
call_user_func(array(new MyClass_Mod, "msg"));

class MyClass {
    function msg() {
        echo '<p>get_class(): ' . get_class() . '</p>';
    }
}
class MyClass_Mod extends MyClass {
}
```

**output**

> get_class(): MyClass

**Example 2**

```
call_user_func(array(new MyClass_Mod, "msg"));

class MyClass {
    function msg() {
        echo '<p>get_class(): ' . get_class() . '</p>';
    }
}
class MyClass_Mod extends MyClass {
    function msg() {
        echo '<p>get_class(): ' . get_class() . '</p>';
    }
}
```

**output**

> get_class(): MyClass_Mod

I'd like to know the mechanism, so please do not suggest to use `get_called_class()`. I'm not able to use it for the version below PHP 5.3. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to pass `$this` argument to [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/function.get-class.php) function.

```
get_class($this);
```

Comment: @Teno: It's a good idea to read the documentation for functions you call in your code.

Comment: @Jon I did and actually it says `This parameter may be omitted when inside a class.` So I would expect it can be omitted.

Comment: @Teno: Read the "return values" section as well. :)

Comment: @Jon I don't understand what this means: `Returns the name of the class of which object is an instance. Returns FALSE if object is not an object. If object is omitted when inside a class, the name of that class is returned.` I would expect the name of that class refers to the extended class.

Comment: @Teno It basically means the class that defined that function. In your case it's parent class `MyClass`

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter of `get_class` is omitted when inside a class, **the name of that class** is returned.

You need to specify the parameter with `$this`.

Comment: Does `the name of that class` mean the original class?

Comment: @Teno It means the class that defined that function. In your case it's parent class

Comment: @Rezigned Oh, really. It's quite confusing.